# GeoServer - Response Time (Rendering Geo data)

Tags: geoserver, wms, performance, rendering, getmap

I'm having a hard time finding any documentation on the acceptable response time for a WMS GetMap request. In the area of HCI regarding usability, the acceptable response time is 0.1s to 1s. But we all know that with geospatial data, the data rendering time can take longer.

What will be an acceptable time for a user in terms of rendering one WMS GetMap request?

Comment: Only GeoServer, what about other WMS server software?

Answer (score 1):

Those you cited are the acceptable times. If it's taking longer:

- Optimize your data
- Reduce the amount of information you render (selection + scale dependencies)
- Use tile caching

See these slides for possible avenues for optimizing map rendering:
https://2017.foss4g.org/post_conference/geoserver_in_production.pdf